# Is it possible to show errors when I write C++ code in C?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have to write my assignment in C but I don't want to download a new IDE just for this course. I want to use VS 2019 and MSVC to compile it, but I would like to generate errors for things that aren't in C. Is this possible?

Comment: Use `.c` files. Those compile as C and not C++.

Comment: This should happen automatically when you work with C code in VS. Recently they've even been aiming for standard compatibility, e.g. c99 preprocessor and so on.

Comment: You may want to add something like -std=c99 to the compile flags.

Comment: `#ifdef __cplusplus` / `#error wrong compiler` / `#endif`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, MSVC will compile files with the `.c` extension as "C" and files with the `.cpp` extension as "C++". However, if (for whatever reason) this does *not* seem to be the case, you can specify which language to use on a project-basis (or even on an individual source file basis).

To do this, right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer and select the "Properties" command. In the displayed dialog box, open the `C/C++` node and select the `Advanced` item; then, choose "Compile as C Code" in the `Compile As` property. Like this:

[image]

You can do the same for an *individual file* within a project by right-clicking on that file, rather than on its containing project.

NOTE: The plain "C" compiler *native* to Visual Studio (MSVC) uses a *very* old language standard. You may find the [clang-cl](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MSVCCompatibility.html) plug-in very useful, as that complies to a more modern standard (it uses the LLVM compiler). You can install it *via* the "Visual Studio Installer" program (if you have VS-2019).

Answer (score 0):

To write in C program in Visual Studio, create your project as if you were going to set up a C++ project, but name your source files with a .c extension. This will cause them to be compiled assuming C syntax, because files with .cpp extensions are assumed to be C++ source code.

Not every C99 feature is implemented in the C compiler. This is an issue if you only want to do some complex projects.